# When to create new Laws?

Tags: the-strange, cypher-system

In the Strange the Laws determine the physics of a recursion.

In the Core books the Laws given are:

- **Substandard Physics** -- no examples given, but described as generally not having better than iron age tech possible
- **Standard Physics** -- like earth, unless  otherwise specified all Laws extend upon standard physics.
- **Magic** -- Like Ardyn. Casting spells etc
- **Mad Science** -- Like Ruk. Clones, fusion generators, all manner of technological things are possible.
- **Exotic** -- a catch all for things that are more weird. Alien recursions, the example of Flatland is given in a splatbook.
- **Puppets** -- never described, but the example of Middlecap (Standard Physics plus Puppets) is given where puppets are sentient.

It is also stated that normally not all aspects of all laws are present in all recussions, eg a Recursion with mad science might only have biological sciences made easier and super advanced.

For an Artifact taken through an Inapposite Gate, to function, the new recussion must support the same set of Laws. I interpret this as it must support not just the same laws, but also the same aspects, eg no taking a pocket fusion generator to a Mad Science biology based recursion. So having the same laws is necessary, but not sufficient for artifacts to work.

It seems like the Laws are one of the key information that a translating character automatically knows upon entering a recursion, so I guess that is a factor too.

But as a GM how should I decide, when crafting a new recussion if it should operate under new laws, or under existing ones -- with a specific twist/aspect?

Eg lets say I am making a [Steampunk Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk).
In this recursion, mechanical computers are powerful and ubiquitous; pneumatic tubes send messages hundreds of kilometers; and windup backpack helicopters carry people about. 
These things are not possible under Standard Physics, so we need some greater laws.

I could say it is Mad Science, with a bent for the mechanical.
Or I could say it operates under the laws of Steampunk. (Or under the laws of Steam and Punk :-P)

- What are the mechanical implications of the choice?

  - so far I am aware of two: it is necessary (but not sufficient) condition  for artefact transfer, and it is something the players are told during translation
  - both seem rather minor since  not sufficent, and just one of the many facts the players are told during translation
  - is there more to it?
- Why should I choose one of the other?

  - Is it just a matter of opinion? Without real effect on the game?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to create a new Law? Then create it, you're the GM!
However, if you are looking for a way to rationalize the answer, try this:

As the GM, the question you need to ask yourself is, "Are the Laws of my new recursion SO DIFFERENT from the list of Laws as discovered/determined by The Estate, that I need to create a new one? Or, do 'my' Laws fit under one or more of the Estate-defined Laws?"

If the answer is that they fit under one or more existing Laws, then, by all means, define the recursion that way.
If the answer is that they don't fit under ANY of the existing Laws, then, as GM, go ahead and create a new one!

From the core rulebook, p8:
"The Estate has classified the following additional laws under which recursions operate: Magic, Mad Science, Psionics, Substandard Physics, and >redacted<."

Just because "Mad Science" may be required for superhero foci, that doesn't mean that all "Mad Science" recursions will support superheroes. (core rulebook, p136) Likewise, Professor Tomorrow's recursion may include pocket fusion generators ("Mad Science", future-tech), but Dr. Frankenstein's ("Mad Science", bio/chemical and electro/mechanical) would not. A PFG taken through an Inapposite Gate to the good Doctor's lab would begin to degrade immediately upon arrival. That same PFG brought in via translation, however, would take on the context of it's new surroundings; perhaps, a crystal diode capacitor, with cabling and lightning rods for charging! :)

As to your specific "Steampunk" recursion, I, personally, would place that firmly under "Mad Science" - there would be no need to create a new set of Laws just for that. (Also keep in mind that "steampunk" includes a very wide variety of technologies, depending on the author's POV of the genre. You may want to be specific as to which tech may be allowed.)

But, to go back to my first statement: You are the GM - if you want to define a new "Steampunk" Law, then go ahead and define one!

EDIT:
Per the "Steam London" description in the *Encyclopedia of Impossible Things* (p16), the combination of "magical" and "mad science" workings, that produce the "Steampunk" genre, falls under the Law of **Mad Science**:

> Steam London is a recursion seeded from thousands of stories about improbable science and magic that have been written in the so-called “steampunk” genre. Steam London has the advantage of possessing technology far in advance of its Victorian trappings, where large construction projects that result in dirigibles, giant robots, and other wonders of “the modern world” do not draw undue attention from the locals (as long as one has paid the proper Mad Science Tax to the London authorities).

The reference to Mad Science, as the applicable law for this recursion, is in the description of the *Railgun* artifact on the same page.

Comment: For extending the question... If I want to create, for example, a ToonTown recursion, should I create new rules, or just treat it as Mad Science + Exotic? How should I deal with Illogical Logic, Cosmic Shift and other concepts from cartoons. PS: I'm using Toon RPG lingo here